# Can't connect with new user created

Tags: sql, oracle, database-administration

I've just registered to Oracle Cloud Free Tier.
After logging as ADMIN to SQL Developer Web, I've created a new user by executing the following statements:

```
CREATE USER MYUSERNEW IDENTIFIED BY "..............";

grant create session to MYUSERNEW;

grant connect to MYUSERNEW;
```

After giving logout, I've tried to connect as MYUSERNEW but I get:

```
An invalid user name or password was supplied.
```

Could it be that even if I've created a new user, oracle free platform allows to connect only by ADMIN?

Thanks!

Comment: The error message is quite clear, verify the password. Note, in Oracle 11.1 and newer the passwords in Oracle are case-sensitive (by default).

Comment: I've just tried to write the password without quotes and case-sensitive but I always get "An invalid user name or password was supplied"

Comment: Follow [instructions](https://docs.oracle.com/en/cloud/paas/autonomous-data-warehouse-cloud/user/sql-developer-web.html#GUID-4B404CE3-C832-4089-B37A-ADE1036C7EEA) here

Answer (score 0):

Just tested on ADW instance.

```
    grant connect,resource to scott identified by xxxx;
    
    alter user scott default tablespace sampleschema;
    
    alter user scott quota unlimited on sampleschema;
```

Grant database user access to Sql Developer Web (database user/schema should be in upper case)

```
BEGIN
   ORDS_ADMIN.ENABLE_SCHEMA(
     p_enabled => TRUE,
     p_schema => 'SCOTT',
     p_url_mapping_type => 'BASE_PATH',
     p_url_mapping_pattern => 'adwscott',
     p_auto_rest_auth => TRUE
   );
   COMMIT;
END;
/
```

Just copy admin url and replace `admin` with alias i.e `p_url_mapping_pattern`

e.g if admin url is

```
https://instance_host_name/ords/admin/_sdw/?nav=worksheet
```

then scott's url will be

```
 https://instance_host_name/ords/adwscott/_sdw/?nav=worksheet
```